# Custom select box

Tags: html, css, select, dropdown

I am trying to style a select drop down box. The custom select box has rounded corners and a dropdown list (a box that drops down with the options) that shows on focus. I used the css below to style the select box. I have also substituted the html select with DIV elements.

Here is the code I have used so far:

```js
document.querySelector('.custom-select-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
  for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-option")) {
    option.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (!this.classList.contains('selected')) {
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.custom-option.selected').classList.remove('selected');
        this.classList.add('selected');
        this.closest('.custom-select').querySelector('.custom-select__trigger span').textContent = this.textContent;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 188px;
  z-index: 30000000000;
}

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom-select__trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 27px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.custom-options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom-select.open .custom-options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.custom-option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #394a6d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select-wrapper">
  <div class="custom-select">
    <div class="custom-select__trigger">
      <span>Option 1</span>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-options">
      <span class="custom-option selected" data-value="tesla">Option 2</span>
      <span class="custom-option" data-value="volvo">Option 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styles I have applied to the select tag are coming into effect, but the problem is that the dropdown box top border does not blend with the select box itself on focus. Is it only possible to change the SELECT input style on focus from a round border to a square border?

Would someone with some more knowledge in this regard please take a few minutes to suggest a solution?

Comment: why not use a real `<select>` tag?

Comment: @tacoshy because I cannot have the desired style with a usual selectbox

Comment: you can if you can tell us the exact desired style. With `<selecet>` you can use the `:focus` pseudo-selector.

Comment: @tacoshy you can see the desired style if you run the code snippet

Comment: yes and that you can do just fine with the select tag (btw. I included the code snippet twice for you). I know about the code snippet...

Comment: Your custom solution there is an absolute catastrophe, from the usability point of view. (For example using it via keyboard, appears to be absolute impossible.)

Comment: @tacoshy. thx a lot for that :) can you suggest how to achieve what I want with select/ option tags

Comment: @CBroe can you please explain why?

Comment: What is there to explain … Can _you_ use this via the keyboard, like you would/could with a normal select element?

Comment: @CBroe you are right. What do you suggest?

Comment: First, I’d see how far you can get with an actual, native select element. Bootstrap applies some basic styling like rounded corners already, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/ If those options aren’t enough, then there’s probably scripting-based solutions out there that handle this a bit better, regarding things like keyboard support, setting of ARIA attributes as far as necessary, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "blending", but if you want to achieve a more harmonious look, you can do the following:

- Set the `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` of the trigger element to `0px` when the dropdown is open, so that the select trigger visually continues to the dropdown that is visible
- Remove the top border of the dropdown, so that you don't have a doubly-thick border separating the trigger and the dropdown

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
document.querySelector('.custom-select-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
  for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-option")) {
    option.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (!this.classList.contains('selected')) {
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.custom-option.selected').classList.remove('selected');
        this.classList.add('selected');
        this.closest('.custom-select').querySelector('.custom-select__trigger span').textContent = this.textContent;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 188px;
  z-index: 30000000000;
}

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom-select__trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 27px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom-options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom-select.open .custom-select__trigger {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.custom-select.open .custom-options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.custom-option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #394a6d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select-wrapper">
  <div class="custom-select">
    <div class="custom-select__trigger">
      <span>Option 1</span>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-options">
      <span class="custom-option selected" data-value="tesla">Option 2</span>
      <span class="custom-option" data-value="volvo">Option 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The above code is a solution strictly from a styling point of view. But as per @CBroe remarks, from a usability point of view (for example using the select via keyboard is impossible), the code is not optimal.

This is why I came up with a solution that uses the jQuery plugin Select2

If anyone is interested here is a link to the code
https://www.codeply.com/p/Z999PpuSOK